# How to merge back renamed files from one branch to the original branch as new ones with git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I had to add some new functionality to some modules in our app, so I created a feature branch, and developed the required functionality. Each module is encapsulated in one file. After I finished I got the request to deploy both the new and the old functionality at the same time. My current tree looks something like this:

```
- devel
  - module1
  - module2
- feature
  - module1 (changed)
  - module2 (changed)
```

I figured that the simplest way to keep the old functionality and get the new one at the same time is to rename `feature/module1` to `feature/module3` and `feature/module2` to `feature/module4`, and than add the feature branch files to the devel branch to get this:

```
- devel
  - module1
  - module2
  - module3
  - module4
- feature
  - module3
  - module4
```

How can I do that without modifying `devel/module1` and `devel/module2` ?

Comment: So you are going to have concurrent releases of the old and new software?  It sounds like you'd essentially need your "feature branch" to be a "release branch" in that case?

Comment: No, I need all four modules in the devel branch. I cleaned up the example a bit.

Comment: In your newest examples, you're showing `feature` containing only `module3` and `module4`; that won't do what you want, as git will then understand "delete `module1` and `module2`" as part of the work done by `feature`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this is indeed what you want to do, the simplest solution would be something like this:

Check out you branch.

```
git checkout feature
```

Copy module1 and module2 to module3 and module4 (respectively).

```
cp module1 module3
cp module2 module4
```

Then do one of two things:

Assuming the changes to these modules are all that you did on `feature`, you can revert the index back to what's on `master`.

```
git revert -n $(git merge-base feature master)..HEAD
git add .
git revert --continue
```

Or another approach, which would work even if you modified other files you don't want to revert

```
git reset $(git merge-base feature master) -- module1 module2
git add .
git commit
```

Now... either of those should work, assuming the changes are really localized in the respective files (and if not, then I'd suspect the "old" and "new" modules might just be unable to coexist on the same tree).

But my two cents, this seems like you're trying to use a source control tool to fix a deployment problem, and in the long run that may not be a good idea.  Do you want to maintain these independently going forward?  Do you want to deal with possibly having changes made to `module1` (the old module1 code)?  If not, this may cause more trouble than it solves (especially if the need for concurrent deployment is temporary).

Comment: Thank you, with the `git reset` approach I was able to solve my problem. To your last question: yes, the modules should become independent after this merge. It's something like an A/B testing, the old modules should retire if the new ones work as expected.